# ReactRadioButtonGroup selection not allowed

Tags: reactjs, radio-button

I have a JSON file that is used from PostList.js class but while rendering it I am getting a type error.

How should I parse this?

Thanks.

```
{
  "categories": [
    "1",
    "2",
    "3",
    "4"
  ],
  "questions": [
    {
      "question": "What is your eye color?",
      "category": "1",
      "question_type": {
        "type": "single_choice",
        "options": [
          "green",
          "blue",
          "brown"
        ]
      }
    }, 
    .
    .
    .
    .
```

This code blocks dynamically parse Json to survey.

The single choice option parsed to the radio buttons as well.

Now the problem is I cannot choose the radio buttons separately for every question. Whenever I select an option in a question it only changes the first question selection.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import data from '../data/format.json'
import ReactRadioGroup from 'react-simple-radio-button'
import {Button, Card, Form} from "react-bootstrap";
import {FontAwesomeIcon} from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import {faSave} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";


export default class PostList extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
    }

    submitSurvey(event) {
        alert(this.state)
        event.preventDefault();
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <Card className={"border border-dark bg-dark text-white"}>
                <Card.Header>Personal Identification Test</Card.Header>
                <Form onSubmit={this.submitSurvey} id="surveyFormId">
                        <Card.Body>
                            <Form.Row>
                                <Form.Group>
                                {
                                    data.questions.map((index, i) => {
                                        return (
                                            <div key={i} justify="center">
                                                {data.questions.map((question, i) => {
                                                    return <div key={i}>
                                                        <h5>{question.question}</h5>
                                                        <ReactRadioGroup
                                                            onChange={this.onOptionSelect}
                                                            options={question.question_type.options} />
                                                    </div>
                                                })}
                                            </div>
                                        );
                                    })
                                }
                                </Form.Group>
                           </Form.Row>
                        </Card.Body>
                        <Card.Footer sytle={{"textAlign":"right"}}>
                            <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSave} /> Submit
                            </Button>
                            {' '}
                            <Button variant="info" type="reset">
                                Reset
                            </Button>
                        </Card.Footer>
                </Form>
            </Card>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not mapping array in the Radio button, `question.question_type.options` as you know `options` is an array, so you need to map it over to render three elements on each question

```
data.questions.map((index, i) => {
  return (
    <div key={i} justify="center">
      {data.questions.map((question, i) => {
        return (
          <div key={i}>
            <h5>{question.question}</h5>
            {question.question_type.options.map((option) => (
              <ReactRadioGroup
                onChange={this.onOptionSelect}
                options={option}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
});
```

Comment: I have tried your code. It shows the questions 10 times (250 lines) each but not the values. like "What is your eye color?",-> ten times